# How manage sys.stdout on ScrolledText

Tags: python, tkinter

I've write a simple app, see below, to redirect help function data of tkinter library on ScrolledText , something like

print (help(tkinter.Label)) on cli.

I' ve use a class written by @Bryan Oakley.

After launch the scipt press 'Load' button and after click on a voice on the left tree.

This cause the writing of help function data of the selected item on ScrolledText using sys.stdout by @Bryan Oakley class

> sys.stdout.write(help(s))

All works but I can't refresh data on my ScrolledText even with

> self.widget.delete('1.0', tk.END)

than using

> sys.stdout.flush()

Basically I'm not able, when you click another item, to delete all data from ScrolledText and write new sys.stdout

Wath is wrong in my approach?

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText


class TextRedirector(object):
    """Written Bryan Oakley
       https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley 
    """
    def __init__(self, widget, tag="stdout"):

        self.widget = widget
        self.tag = tag

    def write(self, str):
        #this generate an error
        #self.widget.delete('1.0', tk.END)
        self.widget.configure(state="normal")
        #it works but generete an error
        self.widget.insert("end", str, self.tag)
        self.widget.configure(state="disabled")

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,):

        super().__init__()

        self.master.title("Hello Tkinter ")

        self.selected = tk.StringVar()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        f = tk.Frame()

        f1 = tk.Frame(f)

        tk.Label(f, textvariable = self.selected).pack()
        cols = (["#0",'','w',False,200,200],
                 ["#1",'','w',True,0,0],)

        self.Voices = self.get_tree(f1, cols, show="tree")
        self.Voices.show="tree"
        self.Voices.pack(fill=tk.Y, padx=2, pady=2)
        self.Voices.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", self.on_selected)
        f1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)

        f2 = tk.Frame(f)

        self.text = ScrolledText(f2)
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.text.tag_configure("stderr", foreground="#b22222")

        sys.stdout = TextRedirector(self.text, "stdout")
        sys.stderr = TextRedirector(self.text, "stderr")

        f2.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        w = tk.Frame()

        tk.Button(w, text="Load", command=self.set_values).pack()
        tk.Button(w, text="Close", command=self.on_close).pack()

        w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y, expand=0)
        f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)

    def set_values(self,):

        rs = []

        for i in dir(tk):
            rs.append(i)

        for i in rs:

            tree = self.Voices.insert("", tk.END, text=i, values=(i,'tree'))

    def on_selected(self, evt=None):

        selected_item = self.Voices.focus()

        d = self.Voices.item(selected_item)

        if d['values']:

            item = (d['values'][0])

            self.selected.set(item)

            s = "tkinter.{}".format(item)
            #this generate an error
            #sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.write(help(s))


    def get_tree(self,container, cols, size=None, show=None):

        headers = []

        for col in cols:
            headers.append(col[1])
        del headers[0]

        if show is not None:
            w = ttk.Treeview(container,show=show)
        else:
            w = ttk.Treeview(container,)

        w['columns']=headers

        for col in cols:
            w.heading(col[0], text=col[1], anchor=col[2],)
            w.column(col[0], anchor=col[2], stretch=col[3],minwidth=col[4], width=col[5])

        sb = ttk.Scrollbar(container)
        sb.configure(command=w.yview)
        w.configure(yscrollcommand=sb.set)

        w.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand =1)
        sb.pack(fill=tk.Y, expand=1)

        return w

    def on_close(self):
        self.master.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Hint: take a look at the code immediately after the code where you try to delete the text.

Comment: I’m sorry I can’t reach it, I' tried  to add self.widget.delete(1.0,tk.END) after set state normal, in the write function as I see on http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm but It doesn't work nothing doesn't appear so. I'm into the darkness...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a delete inside the `write` statement is the wrong solution since you do not always have control over what gets sent to the write statement. For example, `help` may actually call `write` more than once each time you call it. If it does, you will only ever see the results of the most recent call to `write`.

The correct solution is to delete the contents before calling `help`. For that, you need to enable the widget before deleting the contents since the redirector class as written leaves the widget disabled.

For example, you could add the method `clear` to the redirector class like so:

```
class TextRedirector(object):
    ...
    def clear(self):
        self.widget.configure(state="normal")
        self.widget.delete("1.0", "end")
        self.widget.configure(state="disabled")
```

You can then call it immediately before calling help:

```
def on_selected(self, evt=None):
    ...
    if d['values']:
        ...
        sys.stdout.clear()
        help(s)
```

Note: you do not need to do `sys.stdout.write(help(s))` because `help(s)` merely returns an empty string. `help(s)` is already sending its information to stdout.

Comment: Thank you very much Bryan, I've understand where I' was fall, I' thought that must call directly the delete function of the widget or call sys.stdout.flush(). Thanks even for 'help(s)' tips .I learned a few interesting things tonight ;)